# How to get OpenRewrite running without build tool plugins (i.e. standalone)

Tags: java, openrewrite

The description at [Running Rewrite without build tool plugins](https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/running-rewrite-without-build-tool-plugins) suggests that OpenRewrite can be run on any Java project without requiring that project being a Maven or Gradle project. However, I could not manage to get the described class `RunRewriteManually` to compile properly.

When building "as is" I get

```
.../src/main/java/com/wamas/core/rewrite/Rewrite.java:49: error: incompatible types: Stream<SourceFile> cannot be converted to List<CompilationUnit>
        List<J.CompilationUnit> cus = javaParser.parse(sourcePaths, projectDir, ctx);
                                                      ^
.../src/main/java/com/wamas/core/rewrite/Rewrite.java:53: error: incompatible types: List<CompilationUnit> cannot be converted to LargeSourceSet
        List<Result> results = recipe.run(cus, ctx).getResults();
                                          ^
```

Adding `.collect(Collectors.toList()` to the first statement doesn't improve it because the types don't match:

```
/src/main/java/com/wamas/core/rewrite/Rewrite.java:50: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        List<J.CompilationUnit> cus = javaParser.parse(sourcePaths, projectDir, ctx).collect(Collectors.toList());
                                                                                            ^
    equality constraints: CompilationUnit
    lower bounds: SourceFile
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>toList()
```

This second case is more a Java than an OpenRewrite problem, but I just don't get the error cause.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug in the documentation that you should report to the project. Maybe it is based on an earlier version, or something like that.

Comment: Looks indeed like the documentation fell behind; I've logged https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-docs/issues/244 to see this resolved

Comment: Nowadays we recommend folks run the Moderne CLI when using neither Maven nor Gradle. You can read more about that here: https://www.moderne.io/blog/moderne-cli-multi-repo-developer-experience-automated-code-refactoring

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I wasn't sure where exactly to post an issue.